# Div height in % not working, however in px or vh works

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

I have a dialog box and within dialog box body, I am trying to render a table.
I am applying a css class to the div wrapping table.
When height mentioned in px or vh, it works correctly. However, when height specified in % lets say 50%, it does not restricts the height of table div and renders 100%.

I know % is calculated based on parent element but could not understand why it is not getting height of parent's element as I have a css class applied to dialog box as well.
Dialog box would be 95% of the screen size.

```css
.dialogbox{
   width: 95%;
   height: 95%;
}
```

```css
.table-height {
    height: 50%;
}
```

When height specified in %, content is rendered to its full size rather than 50%.

Comment: `I know % is calculated based on parent element` it's not always that simple ... I think you want to make the parent position:relative, then perhaps make the table (which always do things differently in my experience) position relative too

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JaromandaX In this case, it _is_ that simple. The dialogbox has a height of 95% of its parent, but the browser does not know how high the parent is, because the parent (presumably the `body`) is not the viewport.

Comment: @MrLister - tables tend to work differently in my experience ... though, I haven't used a table in this way in years, so maybe they aren't as hard to deal with anymore

Answer (score 1):

As yo.chen pointed out you have to add `body, html { height: 100% }`. The reason is that your parent element is also using percentage so *its* parent has to have a defined height as well. If you set the height on `html, body` (adding both accounts for browser differences) it'll use the window height and you'll have a starting base height for the rest of the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Change your parent element to vh, it should work. Now the parent element has the proper height, then the table inside can calculate its height based on the parent.

```
.dialogbox{
   width: 95%;
   height: 95vh;
}
.table-height {
    height: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your dialogbox is under body 
your need

```
body, html { height: 100% }
```

Comment: This answer would be much better if you also explained why.  the OP's question basically said they wanted to understand what went wrong.

Comment: html is stack element one by one
if your element get more, your html get height
but if parent element didn't set height
element won't know what is % height